# want to install windows 7

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu and dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129058/how-to-install-windows-7-after-ubuntu-and-dual-boot)

i have updated my ubuntu to 12.04 from 11.10 since then i am having problems regarding many issues such as nm-applet and touch pad is not working.So I have decided to shift back to win 7 but unfortunately i have not partitioned my disk but i still have 70 gb free.I need a way out to to first install win 7 (dual boot) then i need to uninstall ubuntu without deleting my data .Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried getting help for your issues regarding nm-applet and touch pad? There's nothing basically wrong with them. Maybe if you open separate questions for each of the issues you face, people might help. There's also a chance that someone has faced a similar issue and got a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can still partition your disk if you have that much space free. However, you won't be able to move the Windows partition up to the front of the drive after installing it. The best way to go would be to buy an external hard drive and move your files onto it before installing Windows over the whole disk; otherwise, you can use this method but will be limited to those 70 free GB.

Open a terminal and

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

You can, at this point, use gparted (running as root) to shrink your Ubuntu installation to its minimum size. If you really want to maximize the amount of free space, you can uninstall programs and delete files you don't need (again, I would strongly suggest backing up) and then do the shrink.

After you shrink, you can install Windows 7 to that empty space, but I'd advise printing [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) first so you can recover any more files you might need. Hope this helps.