# How do I install Windows 7 on a Lenovo Thinkpad running 12.04?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu and dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129058/how-to-install-windows-7-after-ubuntu-and-dual-boot)

How do I install windows 7 enterprise on a Lenovo Thinkpad running ubuntu 12.04