# How to create a partition in Gparted?

Tags: windows, gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize partition with GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)
>   [How to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu and dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129058/how-to-install-windows-7-after-ubuntu-and-dual-boot)

How should I create a partition in GParted so I can install Windows Vista/8 on it?

I would really like to put Windows alone or Dual-Boot (I would be so grateful for Dual-Boot since I love Ubuntu , But I need Windows at the same time!)

Here is the explanation , I have a 220 GB Hard Drive on , I want to resize it to 100 GB , Then the rest as a new partition , How do I do that? LiveUSB? GParted?

Comment: You click on the unallocated space, and choose new partition.  That seems so simple it can't really be what you are asking, so try updating your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't any empty/unneded disk partition, you should resize one of your partitions with gParted.This operation must expand unallocated area on your HDD.Then create new partition **in Windows Installer**.Because if you create a partition in Ubuntu, Windows installer can makes waves, even you format this partition ntfs.

If you have a empty/unneded disk partition, you should delete this partition and then create new partition **in Windows Installer**.

Comment: I do not have empty/unlocated space , I have a big 220 GB Hard Drive , I want to resize it to 100 GB , Then have 120 GB for another OS

Comment: You can do it with Gparted.Right-click to your partition and click to Resize.Don't forget that your disk must have 120GB empty space.