# Dual-booting Windows 7 with Ubuntu installed

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Now now, I'm sure your hackles have been raised by a very familiar question, but hear me out.

I'm running Ubntu 12.04 on a Gnome Classic desktop. I would like to install Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit over it, in a dual-boot.

I've been looking over several links as to the procedure: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiOSBoot

[How to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu and dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129058/how-to-install-windows-7-after-ubuntu-and-dual-boot)

[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Now, there are many plausible sounding solutions contained within these links. Though the general setup is almost always broken up into 3 discrete steps of creating an NTFS partition, installing Windows, and repairing GRUB; my question here is, which of them should I follow? I'm assuming I can't attempt all of them in sequence without farking something somewhere.

The ones that look most promising to me are:

```
> Its easy to install duel OS but If you install windows after Ubuntu
> Grub will be affected. Grub is a booting system of Linux base system.
> You can follow above steps or you can do just the following....
> 
> Make space for your windows from ubuntu. (Use Disk Utility tools from
> ubuntu) Install windows on freed space. After installing login to
> windows To fix this you can install a program 'EasyBCD' in Windows.
> Download it here
> 
> Follow these steps to restore GRUB when after installing EasyBCD:
> 
> - Launch the program and select ADD NEW ENTRY from the EasyBCD Toolbox
> 
> - Select the 'Linux/BSD' from the operating systems column
> 
> - Choose GRUB (Legacy) under type and Click on the ADD ENTRY icon
> 
> - Choose YES to the restart prompt GRUB will be displayed after the restart which will detect the Ubuntu partition for you to be able to
> boot into Ubuntu
```

and

```
> Installing Windows after Ubuntu is not the recommended process for a
> dual boot Windows and Ubuntu system, but it is possible.
> 
> First, you have to make sure that the 50GB free space is available,
> resizing your Ubuntu by using gParted if necessary. Also use gParted
> or Disk Utility to format the the free space as NTFS, this prevents
> Windows 7 from creating an additional boot partition in addition to
> the "C" drive. Next, boot to the Windows DVD installer and install
> Windows on the NTFS partition. Upon reboot, Windows will automatically
> boot and you won't see the grub menu allowing you to choose Ubuntu,
> because the Windows bootloader has replaced grub.
> 
> Now, what you need to do is run Ubuntu from LiveCD or LiveUSB and
> install boot-repair.
> 
> To install boot-repair, open up a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and
> type the following commands:
> 
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get
> update sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair After
> installation, boot-repair will automatically launch, if is doesn't,
> launch it via Dash.
> 
> Make sure to select recommended repair to repair grub. Reboot and
> that's it.
> 
> You should now have a Grub menu on boot, allowing you to choose from
> Ubuntu, memtest, and Windows 7
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

second one is better.

Chain loading GRUB via windows loader (method 1) will cause a 2 stage booting.

First you have to select ubuntu from windows boot loader then grub will appear and again you have to choose ubuntu. Although you can set the time out value to 0 to skip grub screen, On update of kernel you may need to boot older version sometime.

Better is let GRUb take the control. :)

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you more! The second one is definitely where you should go (or follow)! **upvoted**