# Installing Windows 7 after Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu. I want to install windows 7 so it will not hurt my Ubuntu installation.

I know I can install Ubuntu inside windows. But I don't know how to install Windows after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you need multi boot? Otherwise you could safely install Win 7 in a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.10 as a host and Win 7 as a guest. It is running smoothly if you have a recent machine and safe.

Comment: multiboot.  VM is too slow. I need win7 to use UDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu and dual boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/129058/how-to-install-windows-7-after-ubuntu-and-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 will replace boot menu without entry for Ubuntu. To make ubuntu entry in boot menu, you can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml).

Comment: is it safe!????

Comment: @CutieKrait Yes, it is. I've tried that before.