# Help installing windows 8 partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, gparted

I have installed the most recent version of Ubuntu, I always loved Linux but this is the first time I have ever installed it on my PC.

The fact is that I am a gamer and I wanted to install a windows8 partition so as to play games in there, and use Ubuntu for all the rest.
The problem is I was so enthusiastic of having Linux that I installed Ubuntu first, Now I cant find a way of installing win8 and I cant divide my disk because I keep on having windows error saying it isn't a compatible partition to install windows in.

I read in tutorials that I had to use Grub so as to bring back MBR so as to install windows, but the tutorials used old versions of grub, and I cant find a way in grub 2.0 to bring the boot back. Also I read I had to use G parted, but this wasn't effective either.

If anyone knows how to install windows8 in a partition already having Ubuntu please help

Comment: You have to shrink the Ubuntu partition and create some free (unallocated) space for Windows. It can only be done when Ubuntu is not running from the hard drive. So boot from a Live DVD/USB/CD and select "Try Ubuntu". Then run Gparted to shrink the partition.

Comment: Due the general attitude of Windows toward Linux can tend towards 'EXTERMINATE', if you install Windows 8 FIRST, and leave space on the disk, and then install Ubuntu, it should work better. If you install Windows after Ubuntu, it will not understand the file-system and will want to wipe it, and even then may remove Grub. Google 'dual-booting Ubuntu' take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/129058/how-to-install-windows-7-after-ubuntu-and-dual-boot). If you do install Windows afterwards, you may need to repair Ubuntu using a Live CD.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing partitions can be a bit tricky if you have never done it before. A good way to do it is by using a Live CD called [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), which will help you manage your partitions after you download it and burn it to a CD / USB.

Once you have booted from the CD, open the program called 'GParted' and you'll be able to resize a partition by [following these instructions](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition) (Basically, they tell you to go to the 'resize' option in the 'partitions' menu. On that menu, you'll be able to resize the partition freely).

Finally, to be able to install Windows on your drive, I think you'll have to format the unallocated space you created to NTFS. Again, [the GParted guide](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-select-partition) is very useful here.

Comment: GParted is also included in the standard Ubuntu .iso's (at least it is in 12.04LTS), so just boot from CD or USB stick and choose "Try Ubuntu". GParted is available in the dash.

Comment: I didn't know GParted was already installed in the Ubuntu CDs. Thanks for the tip!