# Dual booting of Windows 7 and Ubuntu Issues

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I am trying to install ubuntu on my computer, which currently has windows 7 on it. The idea is to have both of them as an OS that I can choose from, so I believe that I have correctly partitioned the correct bytes for it. The problem is that when I get to the installation part, after going through the boot setup, I get a strange error.

Something noticeable is...while going through the menus, my Wi-Fi seems to be sort of unstable as after checking the "download updates while installing" and "install this third party software", it disconnects only to reconnect when I go to the next menu. Not sure if this is something to be concerned about but just mentioned it in case this might be another factor.

Now the real problem is on the "installation type" menu. My top option says, "install ubuntu INSIDE windows 7". To my understanding it is supposed to say "install ubuntu ALONGSIDE windows 7". Whenever I do select the option and click continue or install, then it quickly takes me back to the window start up page. And I see no changes at all or no indication that ubuntu was installed.

Any help please as to why I'm not getting the right menu option? Or anyways to work around this?

*NOTE* 
I am trying to install Ubuntu and not Windows.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu and dual boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/129058/how-to-install-windows-7-after-ubuntu-and-dual-boot)

Comment: I don't believe that I am having a windows issue.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the "install inside" prompt was used by [WUBI,](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) which was a way to install Ubuntu without repartitioning the disk. It placed Ubuntu on a virtual disk stored as a file inside the Windows filesystem. AFAIK, WUBI is no longer officially supported, so either you're following a third-party guide to drag WUBI into the present or you're trying to install an old version of Ubuntu. I recommend installing either 14.0.4.3 or 15.10, and to *not* try to use WUBI with either one.

Comment: @Rod I am not using any installer to help me with the installation of ubuntu. I am doing it manually. Are recommending that I use an installer? And if so then any recommendations? I see that WUBI supports installation of ubuntu onto Windows 7 which I do have. Is it recommended to use this to ssuccessfully partion ubuntu?

Comment: You're using an installer; your question makes that clear. That's the only way that's supported in Ubuntu. It's presumably not a third-party installer, but it is an installer program nonetheless. In Ubuntu, this program is called `ubiquity`, and you can launch it manually or by selecting the "install Ubuntu" option when you boot the installation medium. I'm not sure how WUBI installs are done -- presumably they use a different installer program, but I'm not familiar with the details. As I've said, using WUBI is ***NOT*** recommended.