# Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot Windows 7

Tags: system-installation

Hey guys I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop now I really wanna install Windows 7 because there is always that one software that doesn't run on Ubuntu, HELP ASAP

Edit: I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 with software centre

Second Edit: My question is different because I have Ubuntu 16.10 and before I followed a Ubuntu 14.10 tutorial and it did not work and I could not boot into Ubuntu! So I had to delete Windows and Ubuntu and reinstall Ubuntu!

Third Edit: 
[image: fdisk -l]

Comment: There's plenty of material out there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is they have succes with different versions of ubuntu but , does that make a difference

Comment: It does not make a difference. Just be careful and backup important data first.

Comment: @mook765 thanks, but u see I installed Windows 7 over Ubuntu 16.04 before then I used EasyBCD to add Ubuntu 16.04 to Windows BootMGR , then when I chose Ubuntu it said "Try (hd0,0) ext2" then I deleted Windows and re-installed Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Best is always to install Windows first. Be aware of the install-mode (UEFI or legacy). Windows will install only in legacy-mode when drive has MBR and only in UEFI when drive has GPT. Install Ubuntu or any other distribution always in the same mode like Windows. You don't need Easy-BCD then, you have Grub. Even Grub will fail if you install in different mode. For Ubuntu-install boot installer in UEFI-mode to install in UEFI-mode, boot installer in legacy-mode to install in legacy-mode.

Comment: Ok um this is very complicated can u say it in a way that a newbie like me can understand?please would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/163249). If using UEFI boot repair, if BIOS use commands.

Comment: hey will this work on Ubuntu 16.10 cos I recently upgraded to 16.10 from 16.04 @MarkYisri, I dunno if that makes a difference but just to make sure (btw im a newbie)

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend should work on all new versions.

Comment: one more question, before I install the GRUB on to the boot partition dont I have to remove the Windows bootloader before that? btw I have a seperate boot partition

Comment: Don't remove the Windows bootloader, that happens automatically. If this answer helped, please approve it.

Comment: I can't approve it until it works:)

Comment: hey, how do I know if I have a seperate boot partition, please help!

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend please show the result of `fdisk -l`

Comment: Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 253747199 253745152   121G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    253747200 253951999    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       253952000 471644159 217692160 103.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       471646206 488396799  16750594     8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       471646208 488396799  16750592     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 253747199 253745152   121G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    253747200 253951999    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/
/dev/sda3       253952000 471644159 217692160 103.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/dev/sda4       471646206 488396799  16750594     8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       471646208 488396799  16750592     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
btw sda3 is the partition I created for windows 7 and ignore the 1st comment

Comment: actually lets talk in chat yes? Im messagiing u write now

Comment: sorry for the stupid comments I tried copying and pasting but look at my question and it will be there

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend sure go ahead and let's chat. Or you can email me at yisrimark@gmail.com

Comment: ok Mark please check your inbox I have sent u an e-mail @MarkYisri

Answer (score 1):

So you have two options if you do not want to go the VM route.

1. Shrink one or more of your Ubuntu partitions.
2. Install Win 7 on an external HD.

If you need an in depth, just ask.

Best, BoB

Comment: hey, could u give me a full text tutorial because im afraid I might break GRUB

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install Windows 7 then Ubuntu. The reason behind this is cause of partitioning, Windows cannot work with Ubuntu being the first boot up.

Or you can run a VM. If you choose to run a VM read this guide:https://www.pcsteps.com/207-windows-virtual-machine-linux-windows/

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help but I dont want to install through VM, cheers anyway

Comment: Well your only choice is to dual boot then. Sorry. Make a backup of your Linux files, install Windows then Linux and install WINE in Linux so you can install Windows files there (Sometimes you will need windows to complete some windows only files so...)

Comment: No need to say sorry

Comment: @Arszilla not true, Windows can be installed second but more work is required.

Comment: @MarkYisri will u give me a full text tutorial please

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend Absolutely, but it will take me some time. I will give you a link when I have it.

Comment: @MarkYisri thanks it is very much appreciated, i shall wait

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend try [this link](http://askubuntu.com/a/163249)

Comment: @MarkYisri thanks for the help but one more question should I use boot repair to repair GRUB or run commands to repair GRUB?

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend If using UEFI boot repair, if BIOS use commands.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it does not work for every program it's worth checking out if you can run the software you want in wine. Other than that you can install a VM or dual boot.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but I don't want a VM, but thanks anyways